# How to get woocommerce product variation in reverse order in front end

Tags: woocommerce

Could you please help me, I want show variation in price based low to high OR if id based high to low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `array_reverse()` in your initial foreach loop. That will completely reverse the order of variations array. Here is [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).

```
<?php foreach ( array_reverse( $product->get_available_variations() ) as $variation ) : ?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much its working fine :) You saved my lots of time.. :)